# How to change the name of the "edit my profile" link in the WordPress admin backend

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, admin, filters

I am really confused at this point. I can not figure it out how to rename `Edit My Profile` link in the admin backend.

How can that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`wp_before_admin_bar_render` hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_before_admin_bar_render). You can play with code samples on the Codex page by putting them in your theme's `functions.php`.

First off you can try examining the object by outputting its contents with `print_r()`, and you'll see all the familiar items. I would probably use `remove_menu` helper and then add a new one with the modified link title, just to keep things clean.

```
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'my_tweaked_admin_bar' ); 

function my_tweaked_admin_bar() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;

    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('edit-profile');

    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
            'id'    => 'edit-profile',
            'title' => 'Edit Zee Profile',
            'href'  => admin_url('profile.php'),
            'parent'=>'user-actions'
        ));
}
```

The downside of this approach is that the new item will not show up in the same spot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alter strings from core code in the backend, a nifty way to get at 'em is by means of the [`gettext` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext).

This filter is applied by every internationalization function, i.e. for every translatable string.

Even if your goal is renaming rather than translating, it does the trick:

```
function wpse94377_change_admin_ui_text( $translation, $text ) {
    if( is_admin() && 'Edit My Profile' === $text ) {
        return 'Edit My Userdata';
    }
    return $translation;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', wpse94377_change_admin_ui_text, 10, 2 );
```

Obviously you can also return another translatable string by using
`__( 'Edit My Userdata', 'your-text-domain' )` after the first `return` statement.